# Does OpenNLP have a stemmer?

Tags: java, opennlp

I'm working on a project and I'm using some features from OpenNLP. One feature I need is stemmer. I googled a bit and found that supposedly it has a Porter stemmer in a `opennlp.tools.stemmer` package, however the only thing my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 13.1) finds is `Stemmer` interface.

I'm using OpenNLP 1.5.3. Am I looking in a wrong place or OpenNLP doesn't have a stemmer implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The PorterStemmer in Open NLP is private. You can't use it from outside Open NLP. Worst decision ever.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.6.0, class `PorterStemmer` is public and available for use. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to be an implementation. See http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-tools/1.5.3/opennlp/tools/stemmer/Stemmer.java#Stemmer

I hope it proves to be usable. If not, I'll probably use a service like: 
https://www.enclout.com/api/stemmer/show

Comment: Sadly, only implementation of `Stemmer` interface is a `PorterStemmer` class, which is package-private.

Comment: @isklenar Not anymore :-)